# Can't open input file Poco.obj or Find PocoFoundationd.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, poco, poco-libraries

I am trying to install an external library for C++19 in my Microsoft visual studio called 'Poco', which is used for communication. Do I have to build it or something? what the build of the library is for anyway???

This is my first time I build an external libarry, so I have no idea how to do it. I opened the Pocoproject website, and followed all the steps one by one, I opened the Visual Studio cmd and built Poco through it : "buildwin.cmd 142".
These are the steps that I followed : https://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-GettingStarted.html#8

After I finished building it, and linked this file to my visual studio include list correctly : "poco-develop\Foundation\include\Poco". I tried to include a file : 
`#include <Poco/Types.h>`.
It said this : `cannot open input file '...\include\Poco.obj'`, it mentioned a file that even does not exist in my computer or the library.

However, I tried another linking way in my Visual Studio : Configuration Properties - V/C++ Directories - Include Directory, I added the path there, and I got a difference error : `Cannot find 'PocoFoundationd.lib'`

Probably, the problem is obtained from Visual Studio.

Comment: Would you be able to link the tutorial/steps you followed? Also, did that error come from your program or the header file that you included? (I am assuming it was able to find the header file). A potential issue regarding the object file is that the environment variable or path (defined when you were following those steps) you set in your project settings might be incorrect, that its not coming from the file in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited now, you will find the link up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from Visual Studio, It does not even need `'PocoLibraryd.lib'`.
If we really need it or actually might use it, then `'PocoLibraryd.lib'` should be contained with the github zipped file for poco library. 
However, all I had to do is : go to Configuration properties -> Linker -> Input -> Ignore Specific Default Libraries, and add to it "PocoFoundationd.lib".